# "Issue viewing email? View email online?" unique link in Codeigniter email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, newsletter

I'm not sure where to begin with this task, so I'm looking for an answer on just the idea of how to go about doing this.

When a new user creates an account on my Codeigniter site I send him/her an email about signing up (very typical). Here is how I'm sending the email...

```
...

$subject = 'Welcome to __________, ' . $firstName . '!';
$emailData = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'blah' => $blah,
    'blah' => $blah,
    // etc.
);
$html_email = $this->load->view('emails/signup_html_view', $emailData, true);
$text_email = $this->load->view('emails/signup_text_view',  $emailData, true);
$this->email->from('team@_________.com', '________ Team');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($html_email);
$this->email->set_alt_message($text_email);
$this->email->send();

...
```

As you can see, I'm passing data to those views to send the email. In the email view, at the top, I have a link that says "*Problem viewing email? Click here to view it online.*". That is common practice for emails on newsletters, signups emails, etc. so that the user can view the email online if it renders weird or something goes wrong.

**Where I'm getting lost is how do I generate that unique "*...view it online.*" link so that when the user clicks it, they see an online version of the email and the online version still has all the data still passed to it? Do I need to create a separate controller or what is the best way to handle that? How do I generate that unique link?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zach,

yes, what you do is:

1) create a separate controller that can display this email, just like you were making a page

2) I'm assuming the user is already created in the db, but is not yet activated or taken steps to be able to login. So, backing up a bit, when you make your user record, also create a random hashtag & store that.

Now, in the email link, set it to www.mysite.com/welcome/hashtag

This way you are allowing them to get a unique record without using an id that they could just use to go look at everyone else

This welcome page, of course, doesn't require them to be logged in. Probably you give them a submit (maybe after they fill out some more info) that will then activate their account

Hope that was close enough to what you were asking to get you through

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense and would work perfectly. How do you recommend that I generate the random hashtag to store? What's the best/secure way to do that portion?

Comment: I simply use the CodeIgniter string helper's Random_string() function, and put it in the user table like an activation field